# When will Outlook add-in API requirement set 1.8 be supported on the New Outlook for Mac

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

This [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-new-outlook-for-mac-6283be54-e74d-434e-babb-b70cefc77439) mentions that the [Mailbox requirement set 1.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.8/outlook-requirement-set-1.8) is available on the Preview release channel, but there is no information on when it is to be included in the Production release channel. Is there an ETA on the same?

Answer (score 0):

Mailbox 1.8 is now supported on MacOS, see [What’s new in Office Platform at Build 2021](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blogs/whats-new-in-office-platform-at-build-2021/) for more information.

Comment: Hi, I have been trying to use the Mailbox 1.8 API on the New Outlook for Mac. However, the Production Current Channel is still on API 1.7 - Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('Mailbox', '1.8') returns false. [This document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-new-outlook-for-mac-6283be54-e74d-434e-babb-b70cefc77439) states that API 1.8 is rolled out only on the Preview channel, not Production. As per the document, I switched to the Preview Channel, and I was able to access Mailbox API 1.8.

Comment: Thank you for confirming that this feature is supported and work on MacOS, though in the Preview channel. Hopefully it will be released to production soon.

Answer (score 0):

1.8 API requirement set is now supported on New Outlook for Mac in production.